# ThickBox Problem on firefox (overflow:hidden no work)

Tags: javascript, firefox, overflow, thickbox

i need a help with thickbox.
I use it in my website, but a function of overflow:hidden, dont work in firefox, just in IE.
Someone can helpme?
thanks...

html and css no problem, my problem is thickbox, becausa it work in IE 6 or 7, but no in mozilla(all versions). look the code;

```
function tb_show(caption, url, imageGroup, leg, ttlTb) {//function called when the user clicks on a thickbox link
    try {
        if (typeof document.body.style.maxHeight === "undefined") {//if IE 6
            $("body","html").css({height: "100%", width: "100%"});
            $("html").css("overflow","hidden");     <!-- JUST IN IE6 -->
            if (document.getElementById("TB_HideSelect") === null) {//iframe to hide select elements in ie6
                $("body").append("<iframe id='TB_HideSelect'></iframe><div id='TB_overlay'></div><div id='TB_window'></div>");
                $("#TB_overlay").click(tb_remove);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, it really helps if we can see the html/css that's causing the problem as well as an explanation of *how* it's not working.

Secondly, install the [firebug](http://getfirebug.com) extension. open firebug (F12) and Inspect the element you're concerned about. Look at the Style section on the right to see what styles are actually being applied.

**edit**:

rather than set overflow: hidden on html, try setting that on body... or better yet, on a div containing all other elements

Comment: You can even use firebug to change the styles in real-time to figure out what needs to be changed to get your code to work.